# choose python version in an anaconda environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

We have Anaconda installed on my cloudera cluster via parcels. We have python 2.7.13 available with the version of Anaconda. We wanted to have another version of python (3.6) across all nodes.

My challenge here is, when I followed the Conda documentation to create a new environment and install python 3.6 on that using "conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda". For few nodes, I am getting python3.6.6 installed for few nodes, and python3.6.7 for few nodes and 3.6.1 for few.

I would like to know if there is a way to choose the version of python while installing 3.6 on a separate environment. Or am I doing something wrong? Please help me.

Thanks
Kancharlapalli

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the patch as well

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6.7 anaconda
```

Comment: Hi merv, I was able to install it on one of my edge node using the command you have given but, when I tried to execute the same on another, it gives the below error. [root@p00813cw-9fcf94e1 azureuser]# conda create -n py366 python=3.6.6 anaconda
Fetching package metadata .........


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '

Any idea how we can resolve this?

Comment: @sunilkancharlapalli you should open a new question for that rather than posting in the comments